# How do I get rid of "Notice: Undefined index" in PHP?

Tags: php

How do I get rid of the *"Notice: Undefined index: color in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpages\cmain\userfooter.php on line 31 error"*?

```
$color = ($_POST['color']);

mysql_query("UPDATE `theme` SET color = '$color'  WHERE username='plmexico'");
```

Comment: You should know that there's a blatant [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability there.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all you should always make sure you clean up data before you insert it into an SQL query.  Your code is [vulnerable at the moment](http://xkcd.com/327/).  The easiest way is to use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).  Another way would be to send id's of colors that you have defined already.  That way you can be 100% sure that the values you are inserting into your SQL query will be "safe".

The error is occurring because the parameter `color` is not being sent to the server.

You could validate the data before you send it (with Javascript for example), and also validate it on the server.  You can use the [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function to test if a parameter exists.  So in your case -

```
if (!isset($_POST['color'])){
  // return an error here!  The color paramter was not sent!
}
```

References -

- [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)
- [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
- [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

Comment: yours didn't work but thanks for the help

Comment: @pab - true :P I was missing a close bracket for the if statement.

Comment: i already got it but thanks anyways :)

Comment: can you stackover flow add friends?

Comment: @pab - no, there is no such thing here.

Comment: that's lame , i wish they had that

Answer (score 4):

The 'Undefined index' notice is issued because there is no `color` key in `$_POST`. This is because `color` was not passed from the previous page. You can detect if the key exists before you try to access it:

```
if(array_key_exists("color", $_POST)) {
    $color = $_POST["color"];
}else{
    $color = "red";  // no color given; default to red
}
```

You should also know that your code contains a blatant [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability. You can fix this by escaping `$color` with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) before inserting it into the query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE theme SET color = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($color) . "' WHERE username='plmexico'");
```

You could also fix it by using prepared statements.

Comment: i had separate the form to another page

Comment: here the form `<form action="" method="post">
        <input style="color:#F00" value="greenhome" name="color" type="submit" />
        <input style="color:#F00" value="home" name="color" type="submit" />

        </form>`

Comment: @Pablo: If I understand you correctly, you're saying you moved the form to a page separate from the page that processes the inputs. If so, you'll need to set the `action` attribute of the `form` to the page that processes the inputs.

Comment: yea I fix that already i forgot to mention, what i did just put everything in one page and also i'm wondering because in the form theirs no text box do i really still need to add mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: @Pablo: Yes, because people can submit things to your page without using your form.

Answer (score 2):

That "notice" is an error.  It's message, "undefined index", means that you are attempting to access an array's value at a nonexistent key.  You should check that the value is set before accessing it (and optionally set it to a default such as black if it isn't set).

```
$color = isset($_POST['color']) ? $_POST['color'] : "#000000";
```

Also, note that the mysql database functions are on the road to deprecation and no longer are being updated.  You should instead use mysqli or PDO for database interaction.

Furthermore, your code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injections in its current state.  You should use `mysql_real_escape_string` (or its mysqli/PDO equivalent if you choose to upgrade to one of those APIs) to prevent them.